# Azure CustomScript Extension -- WindowsVM -- Restart-Computer -- trigger script at startup

Tags: windows, azure, automation, cloud

I have difficulty in automating the installation of an application on an azure machine (Windows Server 2012 R2 datacenter).

My script is written in two steps:

- Step1: installation of the .NET4.6.1 then restart to finish installation
- Step2: installation of my application

**I am unable to re-start my script when the machine wackup.**

There are techniques using **ScheduldedTask** or **schtasks** but it's a success only when I am logged on in the machine using remote desktop. When the script is run by Azure CustomScript Extension, the script is not schedulded for restart.

The goal is to run an ARM deployment, that will install my application using the CustomScript Extension without any action of my part.

**Here is my code to create the wakeup task with ScheduldedTask:**

```
$ Pstart = "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
$ Actionscript = "& `"C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\1.4\Downloads\0\MyScript.ps1`""
$ Action = New ScheduledTaskAction -execute $ pstart -argument $ actionscript
$ Trigger = New ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtStartUp
Register-ScheduledTask `
   -TaskName $TaskName `
   -Action $Action `
   -Trigger $Trigger `
   -RunLevel Highest `
   -User "$Userdomain\$Username" `
   -password $UncryptedPassword
```

**Here is my code with schtasks:**

```
schtasks /create `
  /RU $username `
  /PR $UncryptedPassword `
  /SC ONSTART `
  /TN $taskName `
  /TR "'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe' & `"C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\1.4\Downloads\0\MyScript.ps1`"" `
  /RL HIGHEST
```

These two code activate the script on the VM wakeup, **but only when I run it through remote desktop.**

The error appears when it is executed by AzureCustomScriptExtension.

Comment: Do you need/want the scheduled task or was that just your workaround for dealing with the reboot of installing .NET 4.6.1?  Would it work for you to suppress the reboot of the .NET install until after your app is installed?  (assuming your app install doesn't need .NET)

Comment: Thanks. No I need the .NET4.6.1 for installation too (we use linqpad). And I'd like to be able to handle that kind of problem too :-D

Answer (score 1):

As the task runs when user is connected thru RDP, it makes me think of profile loading. I found that KB article https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2968540 that may be a solution in Windows Server 2012 R2.

Comment: Thanks for information. But as my problem is to run a script at startup, how should I run a script before my script at wakeup ? Or are you suggesting that the issue is at the customScript time (step1) ?

Comment: The KB article is about applying a hotfix on Windows Server 2012 R2, which could be a first part of the script (you may also want to create your own image, but I don't think this is what you'll prefer). Maybe you could try the hotfix to see if that solves the problem: 1. Apply hotfix, 2. define the startup script 3. try it without using RDP. If that works, then you'll want to automate step 1.

Comment: The patch seems to be sent by mail only. Waiting for it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I finally moved to DSC instead of customScript in order to be able to reboot the computer. As DSC is already installed on the windows virtual machine, I think it's not really a workaround.

Here is the code for the DSC:

```
# dscScript.ps1
Configuration InstallDotNet
{
    Node "localhost"
    {
        LocalConfigurationManager
        {
            RebootNodeIfNeeded = $true
        }

        File Download_Directory 
        {
            Ensure          = "Present"
            Type            = "Directory"
            DestinationPath = "C:\DeploymentDownloads"
        }

        Script Install_dotNet461
        {
            DependsOn  = "[File]Download_Directory"
            GetScript  = { @{ Result = "" } }
            TestScript = { $false }
            SetScript  = {
                Write-Verbose "Install_dotNet461"
                $client = New-Object -TypeName System.Net.WebClient
                $url = "https://download.microsoft.com/download/E/4/1/E4173890-A24A-4936-9FC9-AF930FE3FA40/NDP461-KB3102436-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe"
                $dest = "C:\DeploymentDownloads\net461.exe"
                for ($i=1; $i -le 10; $i++) {
                    try { 
                        $client.DownloadFile($url, $dest)
                    }
                    catch { 
                        $now = date
                        if ($i -eq 9) {
                            Write-Error "${$now} -- Error when downloading $url, exiting"
                            return
                        }
                        else {
                            Write-Warning "${$now} -- Error when downloading $url, attempting in a moment ..."
                        }
                        Start-Sleep $i * 2
                    }
                }

                $psi = new-object "Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo"
                $psi.FileName = $dest 
                $psi.Arguments = " /q"
                $proc = [Diagnostics.Process]::Start($psi)
                $proc.WaitForExit()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the code for the ARM deployment (add that code to your VM):

```
"resources": [
                {
                    "type": "extensions",
                    "name": "dscExtension",
                    "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
                    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', variables('vmName'))]"
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "publisher": "Microsoft.Powershell",
                        "type": "DSC",
                        "typeHandlerVersion": "2.9",
                        "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": "true",
                        "settings": {
                            "modulesUrl": "[parameters('provisionUrl')]",
                            "privacy":  {
                                "DataCollection": "Disable"
                            },
                            "configurationFunction": "dscScript.ps1\\InstallDotNet",
                            "properties": {
                                "EventstoreLinqpadScriptUrl": "[parameters('provisionEsScriptUrl')]"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
```

- provisionUrl is the Url to the DSC zip file (with ps1 script at the root of your zip).
- I use directly the url concatanated to the sasToken for private blob (azure cli can return the sasToken or the url with sasToken) as it seems the ARM sasToken option is bugged and does not add the `?` between url and sasToken.